# requirejs and pre-built bundles

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I can't get `bundles` to work in the optimized build, I'm trying to load some  external **pre-built** bundle (not included in the require build process output).

In `requirejs.config`:

```
paths: {
    'mymodules': '../lib/test-bundle/test-bundle'
},
bundles: {
    'mymodules': ['mymodule1', 'mymodule2']
}
```

`test-bundle` content is:

```
console.log("defining modules...");

define('mymodule1', ['jquery'], function($) {
    console.log('within mymodule1', $.fn.jquery);
    return {
        test: 'module1'
    };
});

define('mymodule2', ['jquery'], function($) {
    console.log('within mymodule2', $.fn.jquery);
    return {
        test: 'module2'
    };
});
```

In the *build config* `paths` for `mymodules`, `mymodule1` and `mymodule2` are set to `empty:` (or the build process fail), I'm not using the `modules` option in the *build config* to generate bundles.

If I use the sources as they are everything is working fine, as expected.

In the built version (but not optimized) `test-bundle` is loaded and `"defining modules"` printed, then timeout loading `mymodule2`:

```
Error: Failed to load root module (viewmodels/shell). Details: Load timeout for modules: mymodule2(…)
Uncaught Error: Failed to load root module (viewmodels/shell). Details: Load timeout for modules: mymodule2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

In the built and optimized version there's one more error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

like if `test-bundle` is loaded before `requirejs` implement `define()`.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

**edit**

I've created a branch with the test above to install and build (`nodejs` `npm` and probably `grunt-cli` are required on the system)

```
git clone https://github.com/xenogenesi/HTMLStarterKitPro
cd HTMLStarterKitPro
git checkout test-bundle
# nodejs npm required on the system (maybe grunt-cli)
npm install # required only once to install node modules
grunt build-only # create a build/ directory and the content
php -S localhost:8888 # to publish the sources as they are
# browse to http://localhost:8888
php -S localhost:7777 -t build # to publish the built versions
# browse to http://localhost:7777 for built but not optimized
# browse to http://localhost:7777/index2.html for built optimized
```

(see [this commit](https://github.com/xenogenesi/HTMLStarterKitPro/commit/6a2ab3bdaa6b290f8d1b3439dbd47b8cdc156db9) for all files modified to add the test-bundle)

Comment: An [mcve] would be helpful. Also, what version of RequireJS are you using? Newer versions fix bugs present in the older ones.

Comment: @Louis, providing a minimal example would require a time effort and the environment wouldn't be the same, so, please see the update, if you know how to install node, npm, grunt-cli should be fast and easy. RequireJS version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one define per file. If you want to use anyway, there is a bundle configuration option that you can say that a module is inside an already bundled file as yours.

As it states:

```
 bundle config is for pointing multiple module IDs to a bundle's module ID.
```

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my config to use a *module ID* instead of a path and added it on `paths`, but the result doesn't change, I'll update the question

Answer (score -1):

So, apparently even being `require.js` itself, the loader once included in the optimized version is or at least behave in a different way.

One simple way to get it working is to not include any loader and keep using require to kickstart:

`Gruntfile.js`:

```
- name: 'requireLib',
+ name: false,
```

`index2.html`:

```
- <script src="app/main-built.js"></script>
+ <script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main-built"></script>
```

Still, if somebody know how to include the loader and get pre-built external bundles (multiple modules in one file) working, I'd like to know and will accept as answer.